# How would I use a known value in an array to find another value in the same array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I am working with a strange data struct that looks something like this:

```js
const time = {
      60: [
        { acc: 98.97, language: 'english', punctuation: false, wpm: 96, raw: '46' },
        { acc: 92.63, language: 'english_10k', punctuation: false, wpm: 59.19, raw: 60.99 }
      ]
};
```

I already have the value of wpm (e.g. 96) but need to find the value of raw from the same array 96 came from. I have given it an attempt as follows:

```js
function findTimeRaw() {
      let timeVal = 96
      let {raw} = time[timeVal].find(({wpm})=>wpm===timeVal);
      return raw
}
```

This should in theory return "46" but instead returns undefined.

Can anyone explain where I have gone wrong?

Comment: This `time[timeVal]` returns `undefined` according to the posted `time` object because there is not any property equals to `96`.

Comment: Do you already know `timeVal`? or does/can this `time` structure have multiple keys in it?

Comment: i already know timeval, it can be either 15, 30, 60 or 120 - but I didnt include this for simplicity

Comment: `let {raw} = time[60].find(({wpm})=>wpm===timeVal);`

Comment: I dont see how it can be `wpm===timeVal` since timeval = 60 in this case, but thank you

Comment: @Ele do I therefore have to specify time[60][] or something since it is nested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up the time and WPM variables - they need to be different.

```js
const time = {
      60: [
        { acc: 98.97, language: 'english', punctuation: false, wpm: 96, raw: '46' },
        { acc: 92.63, language: 'english_10k', punctuation: false, wpm: 59.19, raw: 60.99 }
      ]
};

function findTimeRaw() { 
      const timeVal = 60;
      const wpmToFind = 96;
      const {raw} = time[timeVal].find(({wpm})=>wpm===wpmToFind);
      return raw
}
console.log(findTimeRaw());
```